# How to group array of objects by a key with same value using Javascript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm trying to group the following array of objects by the key `amount_per_btc` where the values are the same, and then sum the values of the key `btc_qty`.
Below is the ungrouped sample.

```
[ { amount_per_btc: 2600000, btc_qty: 0.001 },
 { amount_per_btc: 2600000, btc_qty: 0.001 },
 { amount_per_btc: 2600000, btc_qty: 0.001 },
 { amount_per_btc: 150000000, btc_qty: 0.001 },
 { amount_per_btc: 150000000, btc_qty: 0.01 },
 { amount_per_btc: 150000000, btc_qty: 0.001 } ]
```

My result should look like this:

```
[ { amount_per_btc: 150000000, btc_qty: 0.012 },
  { amount_per_btc: 2600000, btc_qty: 0.003 }]
```

I'm using nodejs so a pure javascript or lodash solution will be appreciated.

Comment: for each object compare the 'amount_per_btc' value with the rest of the array's objects, if they're equal: sum their btc_qty values and then remove them. Continue doing so until you've removed all the objects from the array.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qf7roey4/ here is the solution